# php email approval

Tags: php, email

I have a small web app where people can send a message via email to a group. Because of spam I will have to make an approval procedure.

The messages are being sent via PHP. How am I doing so I have to accept the message before its send to an email that forward it to the group?

My PHP:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'whatever@gmail.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n FEJL: Alle felter skal udfyldes";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$email_subject = "Form request";
$times = $_POST["timeslots"];

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n FEJL: Ugyldig email adresse";
}
$strTimes = implode($times);
if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "$message \n ";
$email_body = "\n Code: $strTimes \n Navn: $name \n Email: $email_address \n"; 

$headers = "From: $email_address\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: thx.html');
} 
?>
```

Comment: You should save emails to some queue, and when approved send OR better, just put requests in queue...

Comment: Also clean up your headers - remove newline characters and anything unsuspecting, plus restrict to 100 characters and validate the e-mail address. As it stands, someone could use your form to send spam to anyone.

Comment: @Robbie How do I prevent the spam?

Comment: Timestamp mails, max number of recipients. Use a database to queue for approval

Comment: @adsy2010 Can you give me an example of that ;) I am a noob

Comment: Let me get on a computer. Posting from mobile

Answer (score 0):

ok so this is a fair size project in itself if you want to use a data queue.

ASSUMING you want to use a database you will need to know the basics of setting one up, how to use and setup tables etc. (as long as you have access to a database anyway).

Here is some connection code:

change *peter* and *abc123* to whatever username and password your database has associated with it.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("my_db");
```

I will give you some sample code for inserting rows to the database, selecting rows from the database, acting on that info and deleting rows from the database.

Ok lets start with the mail submission:

This section near the bottom of your code is the data we need to manipulate

```
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "$message \n ";
$email_body = "\n Code: $strTimes \n Navn: $name \n Email: $email_address \n"; 
$headers = "From: $email_address\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
```

So assuming you have a mysql database connection with a table setup in the database this is how you would insert it: (please note this is a basic insert query)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO queuemails (to, subject, body, headers) VALUES ('" . $to . "', '" . $email_subject . "', '" . $email_body . "', '" . $headers . "')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Ok so those 2 lines would be added **BELOW** your set variables.

You then need to provide a method of approval page.

This can be done on the same page but you have to seperate out your `mail()` function from the rest of the script.

Ok so here is a select script now to be able to **VIEW** your queue for approval. Please note that I have added an auto increment column to the table that stored your queued mail. This is to be able to select a line in the table more easily as is generates a unique number for that line of data. This column is called `mid` (standing for "mail identity").

ok so here is the selection script:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM queuemail"; //this is only good if you know you wont get millions else you need to limit it
//limited select:
//$query = "SELECT * FROM queuemail LIMIT 0,10"; //selects the first 10
while($m = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query))){
  echo $m['to'] . " ";
  echo $m['subject'] . " ";
  echo '<a href=approve.php?mid=' . $m['mid'] . '>Approve</a><br>';
}
```

Then finally to clean up afterwards, *after* you have used your `mail()` function you should delete the line from the database that you have sent.

Here is the code (including the `$_GET` variable, this is an unsafe method but is sufficient to display the code you would be using).

```
mail(); //data can be added either from a new select statement or from POSTING it with the form
$query = "DELETE FROM mailqueue WHERE mid='" . $_GET['mid'] . "'";
mysql_query($query);
echo 'Your mail has been sent and deleted from the queue';
```

Hope this helps.

You can add timestamps to another column in the database automatically so that you can verify spam posting with something like:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] > ($oldtimeofpost + 100)){ //time is in seconds
  //do something
}
else{
  //warning
}
```

Comment: thx alot! I know nothing about databases :( I have a mySQL database but how do i connect it?.

Comment: I will add that to the description. Do you have phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: a great site to get info on mysql commands and how they work is: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp I use it all the time instead of php.net I find its just easier to understand. If you need help setting up the database let me know and I will see if I can help further.

Comment: Yes I have Phpadmin ? I'll take a look at w3schools.com. Thx alot for your help. I am really a n00b on this homepage thing. and I only need to get this database up and running and I hope I am all set
I google how to set up MySQL in php but then all ppl can read my password etc :S

Comment: if you want to distribute it always change your password to password and username to username.